# Matching all <strong> tags in preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, preg-replace

We are new to regex (preg_replace) in PHP and are having a little trouble getting it to do exactly what we want.

We have, for example, HTML code like this:

```
<h2><strong>Automatic Writing</strong> <strong>– A Conduit For An Entity From Another World?</strong></h2>
```

We want to remove all styling tags inside the H2 (and even match H3/H4/H5 tags too).

We have constructed the following code so far (we are integrating with Wordpress):

```
function removebolding($content)
        {
            $content =
                preg_replace('/(<h([1-6])[^>]*>)\s?<strong>(.*)?<\/strong>\s?(<\/h\2>)/', "$1$3$4", $content);
            return $content;
        }

        add_filter('the_content', 'removebolding');
```

This does work, however, it only removes the first 'strong' tag - we are left with:

```
<h2>Automatic Writing <strong>– A Conduit For An Entity From Another World?</strong></h2>
```

How can we match/remove all 'strong' tags?  Also, perhaps we could simply extract the contents of the heading tags, run a strip_tags function and then replace with the output?

Any help, suggestions, and code samples are gratefully appreciated in advance.

Many thanks.

Comment: Better look into `xpath` queries (`DomDocument` and the like).

Comment: what is your expected output ? do you want to remove the tag only or tag with inner contents also? `<h2>Automatic Writing– A Conduit For An Entity From Another World?</h2>`

Comment: [Parsing HTML with regex is hard job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/372239)

Comment: HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.
See: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: Thank you for your comments guys.  I am aware REGEX/HTML are not the best of friends but we want to do it this way.  The input string is always in the same format so it works for us.

Comment: @Curious_Mind - thank you for your reply.  We would want the tag to appear like `<h2>Automatic Writing – A Conduit For An Entity From Another World?</h2>` - we want to keep the inner text and simply strip the tags.

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew.  We modified it a little to match all heading tags: `$content = preg_replace_callback('~<h[1-6]>.*?</h[1-6]>~s', function($m) { return preg_replace('~</?strong>~i', '', $m[0]); }, $content);`

Comment: Could anyone help me take a look on my thread too.
Visit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62502118/how-i-can-replace-the-data-oembed-url-data-to-other-html-tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
preg_replace_callback('~<h([1-6])>.*?</h\1>~is', function($m) { 
    return preg_replace('~</?strong>~i', '', $m[0]); }
, $s)
```

Output: `<h2>Automatic Writing – A Conduit For An Entity From Another World?</h2>`

The regex performance may be enhanced like this:

```
'~<h([1-6])>[^<]*(?:<(?!/h\1>[^<]*)*</h\1>~i'
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/rqUmp).

- `~<h([1-6])>.*?</h\1>~s` matches any `h` tags, with any text in between them
- `preg_replace('~</?strong>~i', '', $m[0])` removes all `<strong>` and `</strong>` tags only in the main regex match value, in `$m[0]`.